# redrawing text in java

Tags: java, text

I have a "textlabel" in my code, which activates and draws a label (`HStaticText`) with text via an init function.

However, I want to change the text (string) when i press a button. I know how to make a function to press a button, but how can i redraw this label on my scene?
scene.add(tekstlabel2) doesn't work:

```
      tekstLabel2 = new HStaticText("U heeft nog niets bestelt");
      tekstLabel2.setLocation(350,130);
      tekstLabel2.setSize(300,50);
      tekstLabel2.setBackground(new DVBColor(0,0,0,250));
      tekstLabel2.setBackgroundMode(HVisible.BACKGROUND_FILL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `HStaticText`, which extends `HVisible`, you can use `.setTextContent()` on the existing label (don't create a new one):

```
    tekstLabel.setTextContent("New Text Goes Here");
```

Alternatively, you can fall back to using `JLabel`:

```
    tekstLabel.setText("New Text Goes Here");
```

References:

**HStaticText**: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/googlecode/jinahya/ocap-api/1.2/ocap-api-1.2-javadoc.jar!/org/havi/ui/HStaticText.html

**HVisible.setTextContent**: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/googlecode/jinahya/ocap-api/1.2/ocap-api-1.2-javadoc.jar!/org/havi/ui/HVisible.html#setTextContent(java.lang.String, int)